# List of freely available physics books

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, big-list

I'm trying to amass a list of physics books with open-source licenses, like Creative Commons, GPL, etc. The books can be about a particular field in physics or about physics  in general.

What are some freely available **great** physics books on the Internet?
edit: I'm aware that there are tons of freely available lecture notes online. Still, it'd be nice to be able to know the best available free resources around.

As a starter:
http://www.phys.uu.nl/~thooft/theorist.html

---

[jump to list sorted by medium / type](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6157/list-of-freely-available-physics-books/6242#6242)

---

Table of contents sorted by field (in alphabetical order):

- [Chaos Theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6157/list-of-freely-available-physics-books/6158#6158)
- [Earth System Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6157/list-of-freely-available-physics-books/7690#7690)
- [Mathematical Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6157/list-of-freely-available-physics-books/6159#6159)
- [Quantum Field Theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6157/list-of-freely-available-physics-books/6167#6167)

Comment: I think we should note that we should only include non-copyright-protected material.

Comment: Some other good places to look are: ["How to learn math and physics" by John Baez](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/books.html) and [StringWiki](http://www.stringwiki.org/)

Comment: See also the [old post by Jacques Distler](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/~distler/blog/archives/000313.html)

Comment: @Simon the stringwiki link doesn't work

Comment: See also http://freescienceonline.blogspot.com/

Comment: @all I posted this in META [how-to-organize-a-list-of-free-resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/544/how-to-organize-a-list-of-free-resources-in-the-conxtext-of-pse) to seek a better organization of this material. The help of all of us, with ideas, could be important. My list is not mine it can be improved by anyone.

Comment: I suggest we try putting some order into this post by turning the question into a table of contents (inspired by [the meta.SO community FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites). That will also require grouping the answers, but I think if we work on this together it will soon be worth the effort

Comment: This deserves many up votes, and a meta-answer once thread volume reaches critical mass :)

Comment: http://web.mit.edu/redingtn/www/netadv/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## Books

**[Galileo and Einstein](http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/109.mf1i.fall03/lectures09.pdf)** very interesting book, 200 pages, by Michael Fowler , Text for Physics 109, Fall 2009  (from Babylonians and Greeks to Einstein)

**[Physics Made Easy](http://physicsmadeeasy.wordpress.com/)**  Karura notes

**[Classical and quantum mechanics via Lie algebras](http://www.arxiv.org/abs/0810.1019)**  by Arnold Neumaier, Dennis Westra , 502 pages, (arxiv)

**[by Hans de Vries: 'Physics Quest' Understanding Relativistic Quantum Field Theory](http://www.physics-quest.org/)**
- I love this  'book in progress' to understand **Special Relativity**, and beyond. To see how a real Lorentz contraction do happen (ch. 4) and how magnetic field is **induced**  by electrostactic field and Non-simultaneity (it is like a Coriollis effect)

**[by Benjamin Crowell: 'Light and Matter' - General Relativity](http://www.lightandmatter.com/genrel/)**
  explore other physics topics here http://www.lightandmatter.com/

**[by Bo Thidé: Electromagnetic Field Theory](http://www.plasma.uu.se/CED/Book/)**  - advanced Electrodynamics textbook

**[Elecromagnetic Fields and Energy](http://web.mit.edu/6.013_book/www/)** MIT Hypermedia Teaching Facility, by Herman A. Haus and James R. Melcher (with media)

**[HyperPhysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hframe.html)** - *everything*, in short.

**[the physics hypertextbook](http://physics.info/)** detailed online book, very interesting Work in Progress.

**[Relativity - The Special and General Theory by Albert Einstein (1920)](http://www.bartleby.com/173/)**

**[Feynman Lectures (pdfs)](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/) ([final index](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/))**

**[Wikipedia Physics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics)** a portal to start digging. A colaborative gigantic work.

**[WikiBooks -SR](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Special_Relativity)** a textbook on Relativity.

**[WikiSource - Relativity Portal](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Portal:Relativity)** find here "The Measure of Time" by Henri Poincaré and many other original sources.

**[Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](http://plato.stanford.edu/contents.html)** a plethora of info related to physics (for ex. [singularities](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spacetime-singularities/))

**[EXPLORING THE BIOFLUIDDYNAMICS OF SWIMMING AND FLIGHT](http://library.wur.nl/WebQuery/edepot/16365)** David Lentink
**[The Physics of Waves](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~hgeorgi/onenew.pdf)** by HOWARD GEORGI of Harvard
**[The Physics of Ocean Waves (for physicists and surfers)](http://surflibrary.org/wavephysics.pdf)**, by Michael Twardos at UCI
**[Photonics - The Basics and Applications](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~tcom503/book/Photonics.pdf)** 92 pages , University of Pennsylvania
[**Photonic Crystals: Molding the Flow of Light**](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/book/photonic-crystals-book.pdf) 305 pages, Joannopoulos et al, Princeton Univ Press
**[Computational Genomics](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~rshamir/algmb/algmb-archive.htm)**  Algorithms in Molecular Biology, Lecture notes by Ron Shamir  (pdfs)

**[Motion Mountain](http://motionmountain.net/index.html)** by Christoph Schiller

---

## Journals open access and online collections

**[PSE-list-open-access-journals](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8942/what-are-the-best-open-access-journals-in-physics-optics)**

**[Directory of Open Access Journals](http://www.doaj.org/)** free, full text, quality controlled scientific and scholarly journals (6286, been 2735 searchable at article level)

**[MathPages](http://www.mathpages.com/)**  - lectures on various subjects in **physics** and mathematics.

[**livingreviews journal**](http://relativity.livingreviews.org/Articles/subject.html)  articles by invitaton on relativity and beyond

**[livingreviews blog](http://blog.relativity.livingreviews.org/)**       about the journal articles

**[Calphysics](http://www.calphysics.org/sci_articles.html)** research on the **electromagnetic quantum vacuum**  (with care, controversial material)

**[MIT - OpenCourseWare](http://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm)**  Several courses available
[**MIT OCW fundamentals-of-photonics-quantum-electronics**](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-974-fundamentals-of-photonics-quantum-electronics-spring-2006/lecture-notes/)  download pdfs

---

## Sources to use with precaution

### Preprints

**[ARXIV](http://arxiv.org/)**    **door to papers that I cannot afford (sometimes good ideas) -- Cornell univ controlled**
I follow this archive thru this MIT's blog [The Physics arXiv Blog](http://www.technologyreview.com/blog/arxiv/)

**[VIXRA](http://vixra.org/)**    **free to post the ugly, the bad, the crazy, and sometimes good ideas**
Independent researchers can publish here. The arXiv is usually closed to authors without academic affiliation.

---

## Portals

**[Archive.org](http://www.archive.org/details/texts)** Access to a *world* of original digitized books, and much more.
**[NASA ADS](http://www.adsabs.harvard.edu/)** Absctract Data Service [search](http://www.adsabs.harvard.edu/abstract_service.html)
**[Scribd](http://www.scribd.com/)** - a generic social publishing site where I find books (scientific/technical) with full or partial access.
**[scholar.google.com](http://scholar.google.com)**  from the giant that is changing the observable universe of Human beings
**[Cosmos Portal](http://www.cosmosportal.org/)**  from Digital Library
**[Encyclopedia of Earth](http://www.eoearth.org/)**  from Digital Library
**[NanoHub](http://nanohub.org/home)** - A resource for nanoscience and technology

---

## Multimedia

**[youtube Berkeley Chanel](http://www.youtube.com/user/UCBerkeley)**  with courses

**[Richard Feynman - Science Videos](http://www.vega.org.uk/video/subseries/8)** - 4 original videos (recorded at Auckland)  arguably the greatest science lecturer ever.

**[Videos for Shiraz's lectures](http://theory.tifr.res.in/~minwalla/) on String Theory**

**[Leonard Susskind - Modern Theoretical Physics](http://www.susskindsblogphysicsforeveryone.blogspot.com)** from his "physics for everyone" blog

**[Fundamentals of Nanoelectronics](http://nanohub.org/resources/5346)** NanoHub - Lectures (Purdue Univ ref. ECE 495N)
  including **[Lecture 10: Shrödinger's Equation in 3-D](http://nanohub.org/resources/5522)** (mp4)

---

## Math

**[Multivariable calculus and vector analysis](http://www.math.umn.edu/~nykamp/m2374/readings/divcurl/)** A set of on-line readings (Interactive click and drag with LiveGraphics3D) ;  [explore tab Topics](http://www.math.umn.edu/~nykamp/m2374/readings/topicindex.html)

**[KhanAcademy](http://www.khanacademy.org/)** (videos)  mission: to deliver a world-class education to anyone anywhere

### Math and physics online tools:

**[Online Latex Equation Editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php)** (right click the result and apply anywhere)
**[wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com)** - computational knowledge engine, do you want to calculate or know about?
 **[sage online](http://sagenb.org/)**  - support a viable open source alternative to Magma, Maple, Mathematica, and MATLAB.
**[Euler Math Toolbox](http://eumat.sourceforge.net/)**  free software for numerical and for symbolic computations
**[geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/)**     - Free mathematics software for learning and teaching

---

## Modeling and simulation

**[OpenModelica](http://www.openmodelica.org/)** Physical modeling and simulation environment
**[Elmer](http://www.csc.fi/english/pages/elmer)** Open Source Finite Element Software for Multiphysical Problems  ([examples](http://www.csc.fi/english/pages/elmer/examples))
**[Mason](http://www.cs.gmu.edu/~eclab/projects/mason/#Screenshots)**  Multiagent based simulation   (IA)
**[ECJ](http://cs.gmu.edu/~eclab/projects/ecj/)**    Evolutionary Computation      (IA)
**[Breve](http://www.spiderland.org/)**  A 3d Simulation Environment for Multi-Agent Simulations and Artificial Life 
(IA)
[NanoHub-Periodic Potential Lab](http://nanohub.org/resources/3847) solves the time independent Schroedinger Equation in a 1-D spatial potential variation

**[demonstrations.wolfram](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com)** 7050 applets

---

## Astronomy and astrophysics

### Books and reviews

[Cosmology today-A brief review](http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.1789) (arxiv 2011)
This is a brief review of the standard model of cosmology. We first introduce the FRW models and their flat solutions for energy fluids playing an important role in the dynamics at different epochs. We then introduce different cosmological lengths and some of their applications. The later part is dedicated to the physical processes and concepts necessary to understand the early and very early Universe and observations of it.

[review of Big Bang Nucleosynthesis (BBN)](http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.0631)  (arxiv 2008)

### Portals

[astro-canada](http://www.astro-canada.ca/_en/plan-site.html) Introduction to astronomy, light, instruments, etc.

### Data

[simbad](http://simbak.cfa.harvard.edu/simbad/sim-fid) search data on celestial bodies with the proper tools.
[NASA PDS: The Planetary Data System](http://pds.nasa.gov/) data related to Nasa missions

### Sky viewers

[Skyview , Nasa](http://skyview.gsfc.nasa.gov/)  SkyView is a Virtual Observatory on the Net
[WWT World Wide Telescope, Microsoft](http://www.worldwidetelescope.org/Home.aspx)

### Simulation and presentations

[Celestia](http://www.shatters.net/celestia/)  free space simulation that lets you explore our universe in three dimensions.
[astrolab](http://astrolab-parc-national-mont-megantic.org/fr/astronomie.presentations_astronomiques.htm)  presentations_astronomiques (FR)

---

## Other resources

**[Kirk McDonald page at Princeton.edu](http://www.physics.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/)** a handful of resources on EM,QED,QM (+-5Gb ;-)

**[Springerlink's LaTeXsearch](http://www.latexsearch.com/)** you can search articles by using latex formulas input

Comment: I will use this question, and my post, as an ongoing list of resources, books and other material, that are accessible in the net, irrespective of the license.

Comment: My list is not mine it can be improved by anyone.

Comment: **American Journal of Physics Resource Letters** is not open access and imo it shoud not be listed.

Comment: This is a great post! But might I suggest splitting it into per-field answers so we can use the question body as table of contents? Although I also like your sorting by resource type. Maybe this should be discussed in [the meta thread](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/544/how-to-organize-a-list-of-free-resources-in-the-conxtext-of-pse) though

Comment: [I asked in meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/544/how-to-organize-a-list-of-free-resources-in-the-conxtext-of-pse) with 2 answers. The better I think is to make the OP a table of contents that link to others posts (to be) separated by subjects. I invited everyone to add in this post because it is simpler to organize in the future by spliting it.

Comment: Please fellows: help improving the 'Astronomy and astrophysics' resources. (here, or in a post of your own). There is a lot in the web.

Comment: btw, I found 2 arxiv version of AJP resource letter: http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/hep-th/pdf/0311/0311044v5.pdf and http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/gr-qc/pdf/0511/0511073v1.pdf . IMHO resource letter is a good way to gain exposure to a specific topic.

Comment: The second link (Quantum Mechanics For Advanced Beginners. R. Golub and R. Ince) is dead, so it should probably be removed or replaced by a working link.

Comment: Feynman lectures are down

Answer (score 14):

### Quantum field theory

**[Fields](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9912205)**, by W. Siegel

**[Quantum Field Theory](http://www.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emark/qft.html)**, by Mark Srednicki

**[Superspace, or One thousand and one lessons in supersymmetry](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0108200)**
by S.J. Gates Jr, M.T. Grisaru, M. Rocek and W. Siegel

Comment: The first two parts of Srednicki's book are also on the arXiv: [Spin 0](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0409035), [Spin 1/2](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0409036).

Answer (score 13):

[Mathematical Tools for Physics](http://www.physics.miami.edu/~nearing/mathmethods/), James Nearing

Also available in paperback from Dover.  Undergraduate-level math methods book.  Clear writing, many problems and exercises (usually without solution).  IMHO better than Boas.

Answer (score 13):

**[Structure and Interpretation of Classical Mechanics](http://mitpress.mit.edu/SICM/)** Sussman, Wisdom, Mayer

**[A No-Nonsense Introduction to General Relativity](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9712019)**, Sean Carroll

Comment: Sean Carroll: also available on arxiv http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9712019

Comment: SICM style, differential geometry http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/users/gjs/6946/calculus.pdf

Comment: Can anyone who has read this book tell us what does it have in common with SICP? Just a great title or does the analogy go deeper? I don't believe they use Scheme to teach classical mechanics, but still... :)

Comment: @Marek Well, it at least shares an author (I haven't read the book, though).

Comment: @Marek Yes, they use Scheme to teach classical mechanics.

Comment: Sussman talks about the motivation for the book [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fAY0_pesZ6s).

Answer (score 9):

[Applications of Classical Physics](http://www.pma.caltech.edu/Courses/ph136/yr2008/), Kip Thorne and Roger Blandford

Unpublished so far, this book covers special relativity, thermodynamics and statistical mechanics, continuum mechanics, and some general relativity at the graduate level.  I've read about a third of it.  It's well-written and surprisingly-polished for being a freely-available preprint.

Problem sets and solutions are available on the website as well.

Comment: Yeah! These notes are great for plasma physics (dispersion of waves in plasmas), among many other things.

Comment: Note that an updated version is available: http://www.pma.caltech.edu/Courses/ph136/yr2011/

Answer (score 8):

Sidney Coleman's QFT [lecture notes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.5013)
and [videos](http://www.physics.harvard.edu/about/Phys253.html)

Answer (score 6):

[The art of computational science](http://www.artcompsci.org/), Piet Hut and Jun Makino

A computational lab for N-body experiments. Includes books and source code for doing simple N-body simulations.

Answer (score 6):

- [1951 Lectures on Advanced Quantum Mechanics Second Edition](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0608140), Freeman J. Dyson
- [Introductory Lectures on Quantum Field Theory](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0510040), Luis Alvarez-Gaume, Miguel A. Vazquez-Mozo

Answer (score 6):

## Earth System Physics

**[Radiative Transfer in the Earth System](http://dust.ess.uci.edu/facts/rt/rt.pdf)**, Charlie Zender (All of Zender's books are [GNU FDL](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html))

**[Natural Aerosols in the Climate System](http://dust.ess.uci.edu/facts/aer/aer.pdf)**, C. Zender

**[Particle Size Distributions: Theory and Application to Aerosols, Clouds, and Soils](http://dust.ess.uci.edu/facts/psd/psd.pdf)**, C. Zender

**[Introduction to Physical Oceanography](http://oceanworld.tamu.edu/resources/ocng_textbook/contents.html)**, Robert Stewart open source, accepting contributions

Answer (score 4):

[Street-Fighting Mathematics](http://streetfightingmath.com/), Sanjoy Mahajan

Short book covering dimensional analysis, estimation, and visualizing mathematics.  The goal is to make mathematics easier and more useful for scientists and engineers, specifically physicists.  (Mahajan is a physicist/educator).  Uses mostly undergrad and high school level math.

A version is available [free as a pdf](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/full_pdfs/Street-Fighting_Mathematics.pdf) under the creative commons license.

The paper version is available for purchase from the MIT press.

Comment: @David Don't be ridiculous.  The PDF is free.  The point is to make a list of resources people can access for free.  Do you think that fact that it's possible to get a paper version makes the PDF less-informative?

Comment: I've updated your answer with a link to the free pdf download. Nice book.

Answer (score 4):

**[Handbook of Quantum Information](http://www.quantiki.org/wiki/Category%3aHandbook_of_Quantum_Information)** "an encyclopaedia of everything quantum"

Answer (score 4):

Fitzpatrick's [The Physics of Plasmas](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/plasma/lectures1/index.html) is excellent. He also has notes on [Classical Electromagnetism](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/jk1/jk1.html), [Quantum Mechanics](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qm/lectures/index.html), and [more](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching.html), but I'm less familiar with these works.

Answer (score 3):

**[Chaos: Classical and Quantum](http://chaosbook.org/)**, Cvitanovic´, Artuso, Mainieri, Vattay

**[Mathematical Principles of Natural Philosophy](http://rack1.ul.cs.cmu.edu/is/newton/)**, Newton, translated by Motte

Answer (score 3):

[Howard Georgi's The Physics of Waves](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~hgeorgi/new.htm)

I wish someone would make the (now mostly out of print) Berkeley Physics Course volumes public domain.  Or at least Dover could start cranking out cheap versions.

Answer (score 3):

**[Making, probing and understanding ultracold Fermi gases](http://arxiv.org/abs/0801.2500)**

"A review on superfluidity and the BEC-BCS crossover in ultracold Fermi gases."

Wolfgang Ketterle (Nobel 2001), Martin W. Zwierlein

Answer (score 3):

The **[FreeScience](http://freescience.info/Physics.php)** website links to a large listing of free books on a wide range of physics, math, and other fields of science.

Answer (score 3):

**Photonic Crystals:
Molding the Flow of Light
second edition**

http://ab-initio.mit.edu/book/

Answer (score 2):

A nice set of books have been made available through project Gutenberg, are made available through the [Open Ebooks Library](http://ebooksgo.org/free-physics-ebooks.html), including:

**[Handbook of Formula and Physical constants](http://ebooksgo.org/physics/HandbookOfFormulaeAndConstants.pdf)**

**[Space, Time and Gravitation - An Outline of the General Relativity Theory](http://ebooksgo.org/physics/29782-pdf.pdf)**, Sir Arthur Stanley Eddington (beware of this book)

**[Relativity : the Special and General Theory](http://ebooksgo.org/physics/relat10h.zip)**, Albert Einstein

Answer (score 1):

### Quantum Mechanics for Engineers

- http://www.eng.fsu.edu/~dommelen/quantum/

I stumbled across this book the other day when I was looking for a text on nuclear physics. It seems like a handy resource.

To quote the preface:

`The book was primarily written for engineering graduate students who find themselves caught up in nano technology. It is a simple fact that the typical engineering education does not provide anywhere close to the amount of physics you will need to make sense out of the literature of your field. You can start from scratch as an undergraduate in the physics department, or you can read this book.`

Answer (score 1):

Two freely available stellar physics books by George W. Collins II:

- [**The Fundamentals of Stellar Astrophics**](http://bifrost.cwru.edu/personal/collins/astrobook/)
- [**The Virial Theorem in Stellar Astrophysics**](http://bifrost.cwru.edu/personal/collins/virial/)

Answer (score 1):

Someone has mentioned the archive.org.

I have found [Landau's Course of Theoretical Physics](http://archive.org/search.php?query=creator%3A%22L.D.+Landau+%26+E.M.+Lifshitz%22) there, without Volumes 4 and 9.

You can also get [Feynman's book on Quantum Electrodynamics](http://archive.org/details/QuantumElectrodynamics) there.

Comment: very interesting. legal free online classic books.

Answer (score 1):

The [OpenStax College Physics](http://openstaxcollege.org/textbooks/college-physics) text looks promising as a low-level introduction to the subject (algebra-based).

Meanwhile, looking at the other list(s) here, is it really true that Feynman's lectures (and QED) are legally available online for free today? I have serious doubts about that. Has anyone yet made an effort to go through this list and verify the legality (let alone "openness") of the resources linked?

Answer (score 1):

I am a big fan of David Tong's lecture notes on Relativity, Classical Mechanics, QFT, Stat Mech, Soitons, String Theory and Kinetic theory available free.

http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/teaching.html

I had learned classical mechanics first time as an undergrad from his notes, and I absolutely fell in love with it. The notes on QFT are also excellent to prep you for things like Peskin & Schroeder.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend my favourite site
http://www.freebookcentre.net/Physics/Physics-Books-Online.html