# Prequisite for the Feynman lectures?

Tags: soft-question, resource-recommendations, education, mathematics, calculus

It obviously requires single- and multi-variable calculus and linear algebra, but what else? And where do you suggest to get that background from?this isn't a duplicate because I'm for the math needed precisely and only for the feynman lectures.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193/2451 http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47611/2451 and links therein. Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29355/2451

Comment: Hi Daniel Faust Montana. Welcome to Phys.SE. This is a site for mostly conceptional and actual physics questions that you may have. We do only allow a limited number of prerequisite soft-questions. I close your question (v2) _as a duplicate,_ not because it necessarily is an exact duplicate, but to point you in the right direction.