# Introduction to quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Book recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations)
>   [What is a good introductory book on quantum mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-a-good-introductory-book-on-quantum-mechanics)

I intend to learn quantum mechanics . But I don't have any suggestions about good books to start up with quantum mechanics. I will remain grateful if I get to know about books which start up the subject with the original physical insight as well as with mathematical rigor.  So, I hope the learned people here will recommend few books that form their experience are going to be the best to start up with.

Comment: Well, Hi Danny. You've been in this site for sufficient days. You seem to be like you didn't notice the [book recommendations](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175) and some [free books](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6157). Have a look over there. It might be of help for a good start :-)

Comment: This is a duplicate

Comment: @user14445 Can you maybe post the reference to the duplicate question? Will make it easier for flaging, voting to close etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33215/2451