# Is there any way to read the Feynman Lectures for free?

Tags: specific-reference, education

The Feynman Lectures on Physics probably constitute the most famous introductory physics textbook ever written.  The level of intuition it provides is hard to beat; I first started reading it in middle school, and a decade later I'm still finding new insights in it.  Yet when I recommend it to others, they often have sticker-shock.  It is a three-volume book, after all.

So is there any legal way to read the Feynman Lectures for free, on the Internet?

Comment: @Kyle (if this even pings you) I actually think the original choice of tag was more appropriate. (One could also make an argument about whether the question is on topic here, but that's an entirely separate issue.)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6157/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic the OP is looking specifically for the Feynman lectures which are freely availabe in LaTexed version only recently as Lumo reported on TRF for example, instead of any 0815 standard QFT book So I disagree that the other question is a duplicate and already has a useful answer to this question. Also, due to the new books policy such questions should be allowed now: voting to reopen

Comment: This post seems off-topic for several reasons: 1. Specific-references should be somewhat hard to find. (In this case OP answers himself within minutes.) 2. Whereas Phys.SE maintains several physics resource recommendation and specific reference questions, it is not the scope of Phys.SE to necessarily link to _free_ physics material even if it is legal. (However we have collected several free links on e.g. [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6157/2451) post.)

Comment: @Qmechanic Forget minutes, I had the answer before I even asked the question.  Isn't that a well established procedure on StackExchange sites, to ask a question you know the answer to and then answer it, so that you can share some information to the community in Q&A format?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more systematic and useful to collect all free online material in one single post?

Comment: Yes, it's fine to also list it in that post, but don't you think that the Feynman Lectures on Physics is important enough that it deserves its own post?

Comment: No I don't. I'm guessing Qmechanic doesn't either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The publishers of the Feynman Lectures recently released a free online edition!  See [this link](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/).  This should prove an invaluable resource for physics students.

One note for Feynman Lectures purists like myself: the content is of course the same as the original books, but the look and feel of this edition is very different from the original.  The font has been changed for easier online readability, the equations have been retyped in Latex, and the diagrams have been redrawn.